# How to change firebase CLI debug file (i.e. ui-debug.log, firebase-debug.log) output folder to a separate logs folder?

Tags: firebase, firebase-cli

I have been refactoring firebase's functions folder and I wanted to place all debug output files like firebase-debug.log and ui-debug.log in a folder called "logs". Currently, all my log files are mixed with all other files and it's annoying.

I am assuming `firebase.json` should be the right configuration file to add this, but haven't been able to find this.

Specifically, these are the log files when I run the emulator via the command:

```
firebase emulators:start --only functions
```

My current firebase functions folder structure:

[image]

Comment: Did you solve this?